# Path in an AJAX call keeps changing in ZF2

Tags: php, jquery, routes, zend-framework2

I have a bit of an annoying problem in Zend Framework 2. My js, which is located in my public/js folder, calls an action in the controller for my admin module. This is the call:

```
$.post('admin/expand', {
        id: CCID
    },function(data){
        if(data.hasOwnProperty('info')){   
            expand(data.info);
        } else {
            console.log('Can\'t find customer info.');
        }
    },'json');
```

The call works fine normally, but then sometimes it won't be able to find the action. The console will say:

```
POST http://localhost/admin/admin/expand 404 (Not Found)
```

So I'll change the path in the AJAX to just `'expand'` instead of `'admin/expand'` and it'll work for a while... and then it won't until I change it back!

So it seems that sometimes it gets confused about the routing and sometimes it doesn't. Is this a namespace problem? The js file is supposed to be in my root/public/js, right? Does anyone know what the problem is here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the url from admin/expand to /admin/expand . It is more pragmatic to use ZF2 routes.

Comment: That worked for now. Can't be sure until I use it for a while, but that sounds like it makes sense, thanks.

Comment: It should work as long as your site sits on say localhost but you will have issues if you move your application to say localhost/appname/admin/expand but using ZF2 routes will work in both cases.